# php bin/magento setup:upgrade Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.4

I have recently installed and then uninstalled an extension (Cart2Quote) and now when I attempt to run the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: quotation_quote in /home/49555.cloudserv.com/ngjhhhsssf/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 153
```

Any ideas?

TIA,
Rob

Comment: Seems you removed the code, but the database changes still there

Comment: Try to also delete all data from the generated directory. Run the command: "rm -rf generated/*" on Magento root and then run the upgrade command

Comment: @RaulSanchez - Thanks Raul - I did remove the associated data/rows from within the SETUP_MODULE table test still receiving the error.

Comment: @AmitSaini - Thanks Amit - I have removed the extension directory and all data.

Comment: Welcome @ozmo, Hope now upgrade command working fine.

Comment: @AmitSaini - Unfortunately still no luck. The same error persists :(

Comment: @ozmo Follow this https://cart2quote.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005010223-Remove-Cart2Quote-for-Magento2-from-the-database

Comment: Thanks again @AmitSaini - I should have said earlier. I did follow those instructions to uninstall initially before attempting to reinstall but to no avail. This is getting so frustrating.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. The extension/module developer managed to uninstall and re-install for me. I'm not sure how he did it but it's now working. Thanks again all!

Answer (score 6):

It think it could be a foreign key constraint somewhere in some table still referencing the removed table from the extension.

You can check this by running the following SQL query in your database if 'quotation_quote' is a column name:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'quotation_quote';
```

Or the following command if the 'quotation_quote' is the table:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'quotation_quote';
```

If you find matching results and you double-check that indeed this is the column added by the extension you uninstalled, then you can drop the constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP FOREIGN KEY <CONSTRAINT_NAME>;
```

Comment: That was handy... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to here public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php

and add a condition like below...
In my case I had an issue for "quotation_quote" but in your case, it could be anything...
so make sure you change the table....

---

```
if ($referenceTableName != "quotation_quote") 
{ 
    $referenceData['column'] = $table->getColumnByName($referenceData['column']); 
    $referenceData['referenceTable'] = $this->tables[$referenceTableName]; 
    $referenceData['referenceColumn'] = $referenceData['referenceTable']->getColumnByName( $referenceData['referenceColumn'] );

    $references[$referenceData['name']] = $this->elementFactory->create('foreign', $referenceData);
    //We need to instantiate tables in order of references tree
    if (isset($tables[$referenceTableName]) && $referenceTableName !== $tableName) 
    {
        $this->processReferenceKeys([$referenceTableName => $tables[$referenceTableName]], $schema);
        unset($tables[$referenceTableName]);
    }
}
```