# report.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index

Tags: magento2.4.1, index

app\code\Zero\Storelocator\Rewrite\Amasty\Storelocator\Location.php

```
    public function getFrontendData(): array
    {  

        $storeHours = $this->getDataByKey('attributes'); 

        $result = [
            'id' => (int)$this->getDataByKey('id'),
            'lat' => $this->getDataByKey('lat'),
            'lng' => $this->getDataByKey('lng'),
            'zip' => $this->getDataByKey('zip'),
            'address'=>$this->getDataByKey('address'),
            'state'=>$this->_storelocHelper->getRegionDataByName($this->getDataByKey('state')),
            'popup_html' => $this->getDataByKey('popup_html'),
            'phone'=>$this->getDataByKey('phone'),
            'distance'=>round($this->getDataByKey('distance'),1),
            'name' =>$this->getDataByKey('name'),
            'city' =>$this->getDataByKey('city'),
            'url_key' =>$this->getDataByKey('url_key')
             'store_hours_weekdays' => $storeHours['store_hours'] ['option_title']['0'],
             'store_hours_weekend_days' => $storeHours['store_hours'] ['option_title']['1']
        ];

        if ($this->getDataByKey('marker_url')) {
            $result['marker_url'] = $this->getDataByKey('marker_url');
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

How to solve the report.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: store_hours in /app/app/code/Zero/Storelocator/Rewrite/Amasty/Storelocator/Location.php

Answer (score 1):

The error means that there is no $result['store_hours'] in your code. You need to update the key name to match your array.

Comment: How to update my code? Can you pls guide me.

Comment: FYI In xampp localhost everything working good, when I try on my live website I am getting this error.

Comment: In your template file you are calling $result['store_hours'] somewhere, but the code your posted doesn't have 'store_hours'. Try var_dump($result) in your template to see what the array looks like and find the data you need and update the call.

Comment: I think their should be , after 'url_key' =>$this->getDataByKey('url_key')

Comment: check this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368409/55221