# Magento 2 setup upgrade throwing error . After version upgraded from 2.3.6-p1 to 2.4.5-p1

Tags: database, setup-upgrade, magento2-enterprise, magento2.4.5p1, version-upgrade

I got following error while running upgrade command

```
Warning: Undefined array key "inventory_source" in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Db/SchemaBuilder.php on line 153
```

Anyone please help

Comment: Looks like you are using Amasty modules in your website ?

Comment: check this please https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/368409/55221

Answer (score 0):

Seems your project uses `yireo/magento2-replace-inventory` composer package to remove Inventory modules but one of your modules (custom modules or third-party module) adds a dependency on Magento_Inventory module in the db_schema.xml file.

You can find out which module it is by running the following command:

```
grep -rn "Magento\\\Inventory" app/code  vendor/
```

After detecting which module is causing this issue, you should disable/remove that module or workaround or ask for help from your extension provider to make it compatible with your project.

Related issue: https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to remove which table contains a Foreign keys reference to `inventory_source` in DB, then re-run the command.